# How to pass & get value to jquery use in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, phtml, script

i have one problem in passing the value in website and i can't pass it through query String.my small piece of php code is.:-

```
 <div class="menu">
        <div class="sub_menu_header">About us</div>
        <?php 
            $query1="SELECT id,title FROM aboutus_tbl";
            $resulto=mysql_query($query1);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulto)) {
        ?>
        <a href="about" class="menuid" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><div class="<?php echo $row['title'];?>" id="sub_menu"><?php echo $row['title'];?>
        </div></a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

then jquery is.:-

```
<script>
    $(".menuid").click(function() {
        date_time = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'about',
            data: {"aboutus_id" : date_time},
            success: function(data){
                alert( data );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and my full code is.:-

```
<?php ob_start(); include('web/header.phtml');?>
<!--main-->
<div class="main_btm">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="main">
    <div class="new_head"><font size="5" color="#FC2B5F">
    <script>
    $(".menuid").click(function() {
        date_time = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'about',
            data: {"aboutus_id" : date_time},
            success: function(data){
                alert( data );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['aboutus_id'])) {
        $id=$_POST['aboutus_id'];
        echo $id;
    }
    else{
        $id=1;
    }
    $que="SELECT title FROM aboutus_tbl WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $re=mysql_query($que);
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($re);
    echo $r[0];
    ?>
    </font></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="sub_menu_header">About us</div>
        <?php 
            $query1="SELECT id,title FROM aboutus_tbl";
            $resulto=mysql_query($query1);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulto)) {
        ?>
        <a href="about" class="menuid" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><div class="<?php echo $row['title'];?>" id="sub_menu"><?php echo $row['title'];?>
        </div></a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="contant">
    <div class="con_details">
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM aboutus_tbl WHERE id='".$id."'";
        $res=mysql_query($query);
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $d1_per=explode("  ", $result['desc1']);
        $d1_lenth=sizeof($d1_per);
        $d2_per=explode("  ", $result['desc2']);
        $d2_lenth=sizeof($d2_per);
        $d3_per=explode("  ", $result['desc3']);
        $d3_lenth=sizeof($d3_per);
        if ($result['sub_title1']) {
    ?>
    <legend><font size="5"><?php echo $result['sub_title1'];?></font></legend>
    <?php
    }
    if ($result['desc1']) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $d1_lenth; $i++) { 
        echo "<p>".$d1_per[$i]."</p>";
    }
    }
    if ($result['sub_title2']) {
    ?>
    <legend><font size="5"><?php echo $result['sub_title2'];?></font></legend>
    <?php
    }
    if ($result['desc2']) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $d2_lenth; $i++) { 
        echo "<p>".$d2_per[$i]."</p>";
    }
    }
    if ($result['sub_title3']) {
    ?>
    <legend><font size="5"><?php echo $result['sub_title3'];?></font></legend>
    <?php
    }
    if ($result['desc3']) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $d3_lenth; $i++) { 
        echo "<p>".$d3_per[$i]."</p>";
    }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.<?php echo $result['title']?>').addClass('sub_menu_selected');
    });
}
</script>
<?php include('web/footer.phtml'); ob_flush();?>
```

in above code i display menu in div tag and tage out side so i can click it.my problem is when i click on menu it must take id of menuid class but it's not working and `$_POST['aboutus_id']` not getting any value.

Comment: have you put this code where?

Comment: i have create new link in magento in homepage

Comment: You have do core php code in magento.it not good.. Also  You need to put full url like YourmagentUrl/about.. not about..

Comment: i give answer in brief i have create own module

Comment: Sorry but this is anything but Magento... Some wrong stuff: use of ob_start ob flush, use of include in templates, use of queries in templates and logic that should be inside a block, model and/or helper (anywhere but templates). Also you have javascript code that can be moved to a js file... This is not how things should be done in Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".menuid").click(function() {
    date_time = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'about',
        data: {"aboutus_id" : date_time},
        success: function(data){
            alert( data );
        }
    });
});
```

this should be written inside `jQuery(document).ready()`.since it is
above the element `.menuid`